# If $a$ is a root of $x^2(x-5)+2$, then what is $[a^4]$?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $a$ is the largest root of $f(x)=x^2(x-5)+2$, then what is $[a^4]$ where $[\ ]$ is a Gauss bracket ? (i.e. $[x]$ is a largest integer not strictly greater than $x$)

Here $f(5)=2,\ f(4)=-14$. By considering $f'(x)$ we can know that $a$ is in an open interval $(4,5)$.

If $b_0=4$, then we define $b_n$ : $$ \frac{f(5)-  f(b_n) }{5-b_n } (b_{n+1} - 5) +f(5)  =0 \ (i.e. b_{n+1} = 5- \frac{2}{b_n^2} ) $$

Note that an increasing sequence $b_n$ s.t. $|\dfrac{b_{n}-b_{n+1} }{b_{n-1} - b_{n} } |\leq \frac{1}{12}$ goes to $a$ since $f''(x)>0$ on $[4,5]$. And $$ a\in [b_3,b_3+C],\ C = \frac{7}{8\cdot 11 \cdot (12)^2} $$

Here $[(b_3)^4] =[(b_3+C)^4]=584$ But this is a numerical way. How can we calculate $[a^4]$ in the highschool level ?

Comment: Do you know how to show that $a^4$ is a zero of $x^3-585x^2+200x-16$?

Comment: If $a$ is a zero of the polynomial $f(x)$, then $f(x)f(-x)=g(x^2)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$ such that $g(a^2)=0$. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: Vieta relations and power sums may also work given that the other two zeros are in $(-1,1)$ so their fourth powers have a predictable range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining two ideas from the comments.

Let $a,b,c$ be the zeros with $a$ the largest. By expanding we see that
$$f(x)f(-x)=4-20x^2+25x^4-x^6=-g(x^2),$$
where
$$g(x)=x^3-25x^2+20x-4$$
has $a^2,b^2$ and $c^2$ as its zeros. By the Vieta relations it follows that
$$
s_1:=a^2+b^2+c^2=25
$$
and the second symmetric polynomial
$$
s_2:=a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2=20.
$$
Therefore
$$
a^4+b^4+c^4=s_1^2-2s_2=585.
$$
But $f(-3/4)<0<f(0)$ and $f(3/4)<0$, so $|b|$ and $|c|$ are both $<3/4$.
Therefore $0<b^4+c^4<1$ and hence
$$
584<a^4<585.
$$

Comment: Sorry about jumping the gun a bit. From a sketch of the plot we immediately see that $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$ but we need a little bit more accurate estimates to apply Vieta. The alternative of finding the minimal polynomial of $a^4$ by expanding $g(x)g(-x)$ may be faster.

Comment: ^^Should read $|b|<1$ and $|c|<1$. I accidentally mislabelled the roots first.